# how to use ng-if for nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

doc.html

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="childCondition in model.rule_key[$index]">
    <th> {{ childCondition.KEY_NAME }} </th>
    <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="rule1.childCondition[$parent.$parent.$index][childCondition.KEY_NAME]"
                                                 name="childCondition.KEY_NAME"  ng-if="childCondition.KEY_NAME == 'Value'" required/>
                                                 <span style="color:red" ng-show="main.AssetURL.$error.required ">Service name</span>

                                                 <select name="childCondition.KEY_NAME" class="form-control" 
                                                 ng-options="host.Name as host.Name for host in hosts" 
                                                 ng-model="rule1.childCondition[$parent.$parent.$index][childCondition.KEY_NAME]"ng-if="childCondition.KEY_NAME == 'Host'" ng-disabled="readonly">
                                                 <option value=""></option>
                                                 </select>


                                              </td>
                                              <td> {{ childCondition.DESCRIPTION }} </td>
                                            </tr>
```

doc.js

```
var newcondition = JSON.stringify(rule1.childCondition);
```

current output

```
newcondition = [{"Value":"TEST", "Host":"TEST"}, {"Value":"TEST1", "Host":"TEST1"}]
```

But i want the json output in the below form(nested array of objects)

Expected output is:

```
 [
      {
       "Trigger":"Auto",
       "Condition":[
        {"Value":"TEST", "Operator":"=", "Host":"TEST"},
        {"Value":"TEST1", "Operator":"=", "Host":"TEST1"}
                ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you clarify the expected result and post a plunker of what you've tried so far?

Comment: expected result as I shown above is,
the objects should be part of an another array after "Condition":
and "Value", "Host" are fields and "TEST","TEST" are respective results on UI
I am not taking operator from UI and while sending to database it should take operator as "="